# Testing custom button

Tags: unit-test, button

I am just trying to write a test method for my custom button. However I cannot find how to refer to the button in the test method and basically activate it.
I managed to do this when I wrote a test method for my apex trigger, but cannot find out how to test my button.

This is what I have done for my apex trigger:

```
ApexTrigger myTrigger = [Select Id, Status from ApexTrigger where name='EmailTrigger'];
Boolean isActive = (myTrigger.Status == 'Active');
```

So, I need something like this, but for a button. 
Tia.

Comment: Is your button in a controller or on an object? The code for the button may be helpful.

Comment: Test method for a custom button. Haven't heard anything like that before. Can you please elaborate? Also about the code snippet for ApexTrigger that you wrote. What did you achieve by doing that? Guess the query would have returned you if the trigger was active or not. I am very much sure you won't be able to invoke the functionality of a the custom button in your test method.

Comment: all the button does is call a method in an apex class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't unit test custom buttons in the same way that you can triggers, as you don't have the concept of a browser to render the page containing the button in a test context.

If the button is on a Visualforce page then you can unit test the controller behind that, something like:

Page:

```
  <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!mySave}" />
```

Controller:

```
  public class MyController()
  {
    public MyObject__c myObj {get; set;}

    public void MySave()
    {
        insert myObj;
    }
  }
```

Test:

```
  private static testMethod void TestMySave()
  {
     MyObject__c testObj=new MyObject__c();
     // set values in testObj appropriately
     MyController controller = new MyController();
     controller.myObj=testObj;
     controller.save();
     System.assertNotEquals(null, testObj.id);
  }
```

However, if it is doing something like opening an external URL or executing custom JavaScript, you can't, as the unit test framework can't render HTML or interpret JavaScript.

If you want to automate testing of UI features, you'll need to look at something like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) - this essentially runs a test script inside a browser and confirms the resulting HTML elements are as expected. This technology sits outside of the Salesforce platform so you'd need to invoke this through another mechanism, a continuous integration tool like Jenkins for example.